# Can't type in textbox in selenium can only select it. There is no textarea element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Facebook handles posting to a page you are the admin of differently then they do a personal page or a group you aren't and admin of (where there is a text area). I can select the text box which I think Facebook treats as a button but I can't send text to it. I receive this error when I try to: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element"

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/libertyempireband/")
    sleep(8)
    post_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rc.u_0_22"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]')
    #selects text box which I think is a button
    post_box.click()
    sleep(5)
    poster_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rc.u_0_22"]')
    #attempts to type in textbox, but recieve a "can't focus element" error
    poster_box.send_keys("hey")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! The post_box Variable (the one I had to send text to) after clicking the first element labeled(post_box). This will help anyone trying to automate their group posts!

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@contenteditable='true']")
```

Hope this helps someone!